# Where to place my save button

Tags: button

Here's a screenshot :

[image: where to put my save button]

Every tab, there should be a save button but I don't know where to place my save button. 
Where should I put it?
Is it okay if I place a button below the form with `width:100%`?

Comment: Does [this question](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11180/best-place-for-save-button) answer your query? It's likely a duplicate of your question, unless you have different requirements not covered by that post?

Comment: I read that, but I wanted a different approach..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your form is likely to grow quite long - for example there is longer content on the other tabs, or the addition of a photo extends the length of the form *below the fold* then I would suggest a 'Save Personal Changes' button at both bottom right *and* at top right so that it's always visible - more importantly, so that people for whom the bottom button is hidden will always see the top button.

I deliberately used the phrase 'Save Personal Changes' as an example so that the label indicates the save button is related to the *Personal* tab - not to all tabs. Use a different label for each tab if you need to have one on each page.

If you plan to put a button in both these positions, then I would avoid making it span the full width - and in fact I'd probably avoid doing that anyway as you already have many elements that span the full width and you want the primary action to stand out not, not blend in. You can use colour to make the button stand out without having to physically make it bigger.

If your form is never going to reach below the fold then just keep the button at bottom right.

If your form is always going to be a sequential entry of *all* fields then consider only having the button at bottom right as that will be the natural completion point (in a left to right language), whereas if the form is likely to be edited/updated with a small number of changes *and* is long, then use the bottom and top approach.

If your form is spanning the full screen width then avoid using top/bottom right as the button can become *too distant* from the work area (although I'd recommend restrict the width to a sensible setting).

Currently your *Choose File* button looks like the primary action button (not helped by its location), you will want to differentiate the style of the *Save* button from the Choose File button.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bottom right hand corner of the screen on each of the individual tabs will make the most sense to the user.

My question is - what is with the user completing his weight? Scary stuff!